# How can I connect to a specfic Ethernet interface using netcat

Tags: linux, netcat

I am trying to use netcat to echo some data to a custom board I have. The board is connected using a 10G Ethernet connection. I can see that the link is up but when I try using netcat I am not getting any response. I imagine its because Linux is sending the request to a different Ethernet port. Can someone tell me how i can specify the interface I want to use.

Comment: You should fix your IP addresses and/or routing table so that Linux sends them to the right interface. I suggest adding the output of `ip addr` and `ip route` into your question, and saying which interface is the one you want the packets to go out, and the IP address  + subnet mask of the special board.

Answer (score -1):

Netcat can connect to any daemon listening on a port. That daemon does not necessarily respond. This depends on what application is listening on the server side of the connection.

For example if listening on the server side with `nc -l`. There will be no response. netcat on the client just pipes data to netcat listening on the server. You can redirect that transmission to file to see if the data you send is received.

Alternatively, from the client, You may want to use `telnet <host> <port>` to see if there is a connection.

telnet prepends the following to a every successful connection by default:

```
Trying 10.0.9.150...
Connected to 10.0.9.150.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

To answer your question directly is that you don't specify an interface on the client side of nc.

Provide a host and port instead.

Syntax is:

`nc host port` on (mac/darwin unix)

On the server side, an interface is mapped to an ip. This is done automatically if dhcp is present and configured. Or you can set it up statically.

Once you identify your ip with `ip addr`, you can listen with nc as documented here: https://serverfault.com/questions/512333/how-can-i-configure-netcat-or-some-other-stock-linux-utility-to-listen-on-a-sp#512337

However the netcat client can speak to most if not all other applications listening on a port. Refer to your specific documentation for whatever service you are connecting to on how to attach that service to a specific ip. In many cases if not all cases if you do not specify an ip. The daemon listens on all ports for every interface that is up.

You can see this with:

`netstat -nlpt`

0.0.0.0 indicates the service will reply incoming  messages on any ip/interface at the give port.